# Creating dynamic meta tags Napili template

Tags: napili, seo

Is it possible to add dynamic meta tags in the head section of the Napili template?

Say for example that I have an entry called "description" on my custom object and I want to render that for SEO purposes

keep in mind that in this example the meta tag description would change from page to page rather than being the same across all the pages.

We have one option to add extra meta tags to the Napili template through 
Builder but it once again is static instead of dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported at the moment, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.community_templates.meta/community_templates/community_builder_page_head.htm?search_text=case) states that all tags added to the Head Markup are applied to all pages equally except to the login.

Comment: That is the same documentation I found and I am surprised to know SF does not give us the flexibility to change the MetaTags as needed even with a custom component.